# JavaScript code executes but fails to run full script with no error

Tags: javascript

Start of code:

[image: start of code]

```
// import the robotjs library
let robot = require("robotjs");

function main() {
 sleep(500);// infinite loop.
while (true) {
let demo = finddemo();
// If no demo exit loop and send error.
if (demo == false) {
    console.log("Could not find demo");
break; 
}

//Choose demo
robot.moveMouse(demo.x, demo.y);
robot.mouseClick();
    sleep(2500);

}
}

function finddemo() {
const x = 532, y = 828, width = 1920, height = 1080;
let img = robot.screen.capture(x, y, width, height);

let demo_colors = ["#468a31", "2a720d", "5eba43", "0d7c11"];

for (const i = 0; i < 1000; i+1) {
    let random_x = getRandomInt(0, width-1);
    let random_y = getRandomInt(0, height-1);
    const sample_color = img.colorAt(random_x, random_y);

    if (demo_colors.includes(sample_color)) {
        const screen_x = random_x + x;
        const screen_y = random_y + y;

        console.log("Found demo at: " + screen_x + ", " + screen_y + "color" + sample_color);
        return {x: screen_x, y: screen_y};
    }

 }

 //did not find demo color in ss.
 return false;
}

function sleep(ms) {
Atomics.wait(new Int32Array(new SharedArrayBuffer(4)), 0, 0, ms);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
min = Math.ceil(min);
max = Math.floor(max);
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

main();
```

I'm having issues with my code staying stuck at starting...
it suppose to start my log will tell me starting... then it should execute taking a screenshot and finding a color code I have set. but it doesn't. I have tried googling a solution. I've joined many discords but to no avail. please any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code seems pretty good IMO. Have you tried putting even more `console.log` around to see which exact function or which exact code part is not functioning as you want, i.e Put a `console.log` at "did not find demo", Put a `console.log` in `getRandomInt`, etc. ? Did the line ""Found demo at: " + screen_x + ", " + screen_y + "color" + sample_color" get printed out ?

Comment: no it never makes it that far. so i guess that tells me the area i need to be focused on to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Main issue I think I see: you're not waiting for finddemo to finish its work before you move on. I would presume that robots actions are happening asynchronously so you need to make sure that when you call finddemo that the actual return is happening before you move on to reference it.

Your script reads like you're expecting it to work like PHP!

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/javascript-wait-for-function-to-finish/

Answer (score -1):

You have set true as the iteration parameter to your `while` loop!
It blocks instantly!
Use `setInteral(function, 20)`.

Comment: like this 

// infinite loop.
    while (setInteral(function, 20)) {
    let demo = finddemo();
    // If no demo exit loop and send error.
    if (demo == false) {
        console.log("Could not find demo");
    break;